# Migration to spring-boot 3.2.0 from 3.1.5 give issues on test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-security

We recently migrated to spring boot parent 3.2.0 from 3.1.5:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.0</version>
  <relativePath />
</parent>
```

Since tyhen our unit tests are failing with

```
[ERROR] nl.gateway.WebControllerTest.indexRNB -- Time elapsed: 0.012 s <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: Range for response status value 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR expected:<SUCCESSFUL> but was:<SERVER_ERROR>
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:59)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.StatusAssertions.lambda$assertSeriesAndReturn$5(StatusAssertions.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.ExchangeResult.assertWithDiagnostics(ExchangeResult.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.StatusAssertions.assertSeriesAndReturn(StatusAssertions.java:243)
    at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.StatusAssertions.is2xxSuccessful(StatusAssertions.java:187)
    at nl.gateway.WebControllerTest.indexRNB(WebControllerTest.java:100)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
```

error on intellij says:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or single unique constructor found for interface org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user.OidcUser
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.getResolvableConstructor(BeanUtils.java:267) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.test.web.reactive.server.SecurityMockServerConfigurers$MutatorFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.test.web.reactive.server.SecurityMockServerConfigurers$OAuth2ClientMutator$$Lambda$1094/0x00000008011c7c38 [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.test.web.reactive.server.SecurityMockServerConfigurers$SetupMutatorFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
```

I have tried to downgrade to multiple libraries but no luck.

unit test looks like this:

```
@Test
    void indexRNB() {
        client
                .mutateWith(mockOidcLogin().idToken(id -> id
                        .subject("Subject A")
                        .claim("groups", List.of("ORG-RNB"))))
                .get().uri("/").exchange()
                .expectStatus().is2xxSuccessful()
                .expectBody().consumeWith(response -> assertThat(new String(response.getResponseBody()))
                        .contains(">Logout Subject A"));
    }
```

controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/")
    public String getIndex(
            @AuthenticationPrincipal(errorOnInvalidType = true) OidcUser user,
            @RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> params,
            Model model,
            @Value("${aggregatedvolumes.suppliers}") List<String> aggregatedvolumesSuppliers) {
        // Conditionally show links
        return "root";
    }
```

any idea what changed between spring 3.1.5 and 3.2.0 that can cause this issue?

i tried to downgrade multiple libraries expecting the tests to succeed

Comment: Have you check the release notes for SB 3.2.X https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.2-Release-Notes ?

Comment: Can you show the relevant controller?

Comment: The test failing isn't calling `mockOAuth2Login` (which creates the `OAuth2LoginMutator`) ? The example shown (calling `mockOidcLogin`) is creating `OidcLoginMutator` and thus shouldn't create a failing `OAuth2LoginMutator`

Comment: @khmarbaise absolutely but didn't find something relevant to the issue i am having.

Comment: @LaurentSchoelens i tried as well with mockOAuth2Login but same issue
```
client
    .mutateWith(mockOAuth2Login())
    .get().uri("/?p=/somepage").exchange()
```

No primary or single unique constructor found for interface org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user.OidcUser

Comment: Could you share your `pom.xml` ?

Comment: From what I've seen too, the `OidcLoginMutator` is based on `OAuth2LoginMutator`...

Comment: I'd suggest waiting for SB 3.2.1 release, since many regressions where introduced in [Spring 6.1.1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues?q=is%3Aclosed+milestone%3A6.1.2+label%3A%22type%3A+regression%22) / [SB 3.2.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues?q=is%3Aissue+label%3A%22type%3A+regression%22+milestone%3A3.2.1+is%3Aclosed)

Comment: I am honestly lost, cause i am doing to my idea exactly as in 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/test/web/oauth2.html#webflux-testing-oidc-login-claims

Comment: Does the same thing work outside of the test (when executing the request normally)? Also, Spring Boot 3.2.1 [has been released by now](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v3.2.1), you don't need to wait for it.

Comment: outside the test works, gonna try spring boot 3.2.1 thanks!

Comment: thanks guys, it seems that upgrading to 3.2.1 does the work!!